# CentOS 6.3. SSH. Bind to port xxx on 0.0.0.0 failed: Permission denied

Tags: ssh, centos

CentOS 6.3 Minimal Configuration. Installed SSH Server, port 22. All works correctly.
I change port 22 on 777 and restart sshd and see in logs:

```
Jul 26 01:01:07 myserver sshd[1590]: error: Bind to port 777 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Permission denied.
Jul 26 01:01:07 myserver sshd[1590]: error: Bind to port 777 on :: failed: Permission denied.
Jul 26 01:01:07 myserver sshd[1590]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
```

/etc/sysconfig/iptables contains:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 777 -j ACCEPT
```

*netstat -tulpn | grep :22* and *netstat -tulpn | grep :777* return nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 777 is dedicated for Multiling HTTP and even though not in use you can't bind to it. If you try for example to bind to port 8777 it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know it. This port succesfully work in Ubuntu since past year.

Comment: The problem is that SELinux won't allow ssh to run on another port. On CentOS with SELinux enabled it won't run on port 8777 either.

Answer (score 10):

Centos uses SELinux by default and I don't think Ubuntu does (or least I've not seen it). Have a look for SElinux permission errors in your logs too.

Answer (score 7):

SELinux does not allow sshd to be run on another port on a default install of CentOS 6.3. Follow -> https://blog.tinned-software.net/change-ssh-port-in-centos-with-selinux/ :

- dig a hole into your firewall (you already did that)
- add a rule for SELinux to allow sshd to be run on port 777: `sudo semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 777`

Answer (score 4):

you can disable selinux with command sudo setenforce 0.

sudo setenforce 0

firewall-cmd --add-port=777/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload

Answer (score 2):

The problem is informing SELinux, but I think there are two cases:

1. the port is not already allocated for a built-in service, in such case, this may work:

   ```
   sudo semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 22777
   ```
2. the port is overwriting some existing service (don't ask me why); in this case this slightly different syntax is necessary:

   ```
   sudo semanage port --modify -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 777
   ```

Of course, such ports should be then made available by updating the firewall:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=22777/tcp --permanent
```

or

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=777/tcp --permanent
```

and then:

```
sudo firewal-cmd --reload
```